# How to prevent XSS in the following code?

Tags: javascript, web, xss

I wrote some code in HTML5 + Javascript, that when a User enters his name in User, then it gets reflected back like "`Hello <user>`" .Now this script is vulnerable to XSS (Cross site scripting).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Forms Welcome</title>

<script>
function write_name(){

    var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('welcome');
    var name =  document.getElementById('name');
    welcome_parra.innerHTML = "welcome " + name.value;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="welcome"></p>
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" id="name"/>
        <input type="button" value="done"onclick="write_name();">
    </form>
 /body>

</title>
```

Now, when I enter the payload `"><img src=x onerror=prompt(404)>`, I get a prompt of XSS. So how do I rectify it?

Can anyone please check the host, try and patch the bug and give me a reason?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow!
I've edited your question, you should put the code in your question, instead of in an external link :D

Comment: It's not _really_ vulnerable to XSS because nobody can enter text and click the button apart from the user. It's a sort of ["self XSS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS) I guess, but then they could do that via developer tools.

Comment: Yes, it is not vulnerable to Stored XSS, but Self XSS. But as a developer, we also need to prevent that too :) @SilverlightFox

Comment: Yes, it's always good to properly encode for functional reasons too - many fewer bugs that way.

Answer (score 6):

You can HTML-encode the input to make it XSS-safe.
Add function:

```
function escapeInput(input) {
    return String(input)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

And encode user input:

```
<script>
function write_name(){

    var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('welcome');
    var name =  document.getElementById('name');
    welcome_parra.innerHTML = "welcome " + escapeInput(name.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great . Tried it out. Thank you so much Pavel Morshenyuk for the Help :)

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following:

```
function checkInput(string) {
    var regex = /^[^0-9*\\\^\/<>_#']+$/;
    if(regex.test(string)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way you would find out whether letters are used for XSS Attacks and then, just dont send the form

Instead of the above I also use this function for the validation of forms :

```
checkField:function(string, type) {
    var regex;
    switch (type) {
        case "number":
            regex = /^[\d]+$/;
            break;
        case "string":
            regex = /^[^0-9*\\\^\/<>_#']+$/;
            break;
        case "email":
            regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7})+$/;
            break;
    }
    if (regex.test(string)) {
         return true;
    } 
    return false;
},
```

where you can add as many cases as u want and need to. I hope this could help you in any way

But to be 100% safe of xss attacks you have to validate the form on the server , therefore I follow 2 simple rules: 
Rule Number One: Never use form data´s unchecked 
Rule Number Two: Never use form data´s without replacing script or code relevant pieces like <%>/\ and so on 
Since I could simple copy your form and send it to the exact address, I would bypass a client side check / validation but for your case, since you dont send the Form to somewhere else, the preventing for entering code should be enough

UPDATE:

Javascript compiles some fancy xss attacks on brainfuck base, just for instance

```
(+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]+[+!+[]]+([][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]])()
```

which will give out 1 in alert window...

Those used letters should be checked aswell

Comment: Thank you @TeaTime . Yes, validation of form also helped. I also tried HTML - encode too which also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just assign to `innerText` instead of `innerHtml`.

```
welcome_parra.innerText = "welcome " + name.value;
```